# Google OpenID+Oauth hybrid mode login with internal return URL - OAuth does not work

Tags: oauth, openid

I'm trying to make Google [OpenID/OAuth hybrid](http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OpenID.html#endpoint) sign-in work. The problem is it is an installable web all (so no fixed domain) and I'm also trying to make it work on my development machine - so the return URL is something like `http://localhost:8000/test/index.php`.

I've used the [code from their demo](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-samples/source/browse/#svn/trunk/hybrid) but while OpenID returns just fine, OAuth part is being totally ignored by Google (so I get `You are not authenticated`). I suspect it is because of OpenID params not matching consumer keys, but I am at loss about how to make it work. I tried to use anonymous/anonymous as OAuth keys, it does not produce the desired effect. Any ideas what can be done to make it work in hybrid mode with my setup?

Answer (score 1):

Our API connection details are in a config, e.g., clientId, emailAddress, redirectUris are stashed in an XML file. We have several config sets, e.g. one for dev and one for prod. Each environment knows which one to use. We're using Grails so when grails starts, it selects the dev context and we use the dev configs.

Now to get the redirectUri to point to localhost so you can work on your local machine, login to the Google APIs console (https://code.google.com/apis/console/), add another "Client ID for web applications" and set the Redirect URIs to your localhost. Now you should have two Client IDs, one for dev and one for prod. Jam those settings in a dev only config file and you're good to go.